# What to do if i have 1000 column in this given example in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Aftere load data from csv file then list look like below and first column unique id and rest 999 have data value. I want to sum duplicate records based on unique id. How to simplify the code because I have to write 999 array?

Below code for one unique id and 2 data values (this code ok for 2 column):

```
Integer[] dataPeriod = new Integer[]{101, 2, 4};
Integer[] dataPeriod1 = new Integer[]{102, 3, 5};
Integer[] dataPeriod2 = new Integer[]{101, 4, 6};
Integer[] dataPeriod3 = new Integer[]{102, 5, 7};
Integer[] dataPeriod4 = new Integer[]{102, 7, 9};
Integer[][] data = {dataPeriod, dataPeriod1, dataPeriod2, dataPeriod3, dataPeriod4};

Collection<Integer[]> value = Arrays.stream(data).collect(Collectors.toMap(ints -> ints[0],
            Function.identity(), (a1, a2) -> {
                a1[1] += a2[1];
                a1[2] += a2[2];
                return a1;
            })).values();
```

what if list like below:

```
Integer[] dataPeriod = new Integer[]{101, 2, 4,..................,1000th};
Integer[] dataPeriod1 = new Integer[]{102, 3, 5,..................,1000th};
Integer[] dataPeriod2 = new Integer[]{101, 4, 6,..................,1000th};
Integer[] dataPeriod3 = new Integer[]{102, 5, 7,..................,1000th};
Integer[] dataPeriod4 = new Integer[]{102, 7, 9,..................,1000th};
Integer[][] data = {dataPeriod, dataPeriod1, dataPeriod2, dataPeriod3, dataPeriod4,..................,dataPeriod999th};
Collection<Integer[]> value = Arrays.stream(data).collect(Collectors.toMap(ints -> ints[0],
            Function.identity(), (a1, a2) -> {
                a1[1] += a2[1];
                a1[2] += a2[2];
                ..... += ....;
                ..... += ....;
                ..... += ....;
                ..... += ....;
                ..... += ....;
                a1[999] += a2[999];
           [simplify the code because I have to write 999 array?]
                return a1;
            })).values();
```

Expected OP:

```
[0] = {101, 6, 10}
[1] = {102, 15, 21}
```

Comment: The most efficient time to do this is at parse time of the CSV file. The most efficient way to do this is with an appropriate data structure. You've identified _key_ s having associated _values_ - a flat array is getting in your way.

Comment: What’s the problem with using a loop `for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) a1[i] += a2[i]`? It’s just an array…

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Comment: @RishiKumar It would be very simple if instead of an array you had `List<List<Integer>>` instead of `List<Integer[]>`.  This is because lists can alter their size as needed but arrays can not.  But the array can be done if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Since you are reading from a csv file, you can do it on the fly. Here is a sample data file.

```
101, 2, 4
102, 3, 5
101, 4, 6
102, 5, 7
102, 7, 9
```

- use a scanner to open the file
- split the line
- get the numeric id
- either create the entry value with id as first value in list or add sum to list.
- after summing columns in with same id, convert to List<Integer[]> and print

```
Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<>();
try (Scanner scan =
        new Scanner(new File("f:/testData.txt"))) {
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        int[] vals = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        
        // initialize the array if absent
        Integer[] arr = map.computeIfAbsent(vals[0], v -> {
            Integer[] a = new Integer[vals.length];
            Arrays.fill(a,0);
            a[0] = vals[0];
            return a;
        });
        
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] += vals[i];
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

list.forEach(a->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

prints

```
[101, 6, 10]
[102, 15, 21]
```

Comment: Expected OP:
  [0] = {101, 6, 10}
  [1] = {102, 15, 21}

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand that.

Comment: Thanks, WJS.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java existing summing reduce method:

```
Integer sum = integers.stream()
.reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```